# Is there a specific word in English (a noun) for the strong smell of spaces like cellars, basements and storerooms?

Tags: single-word-requests

Due to the lack of sunlight, usually located fully underground in the house and kept shut almost all the time , basements tend to release a very strong odour that fills your nostrils whenever you open the door. It’s a very characteristic kind of smell --a combination of the smell of moisture, mildew and the goods stored in the room.

I’m interested to know if English has a specific term for this smell.

Comment: Musty comes to mind

Comment: Dank could also describe the smell (as well the cellar).

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not looking for an adjective but rather a noun.

Answer (score 16):

[Musty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/musty) - having an odour or flavour suggestive of mould, as old buildings, long-closed rooms, or stale food.

The room had a [mustiness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mustiness) about it

Update: NGRAM [Musty room vs musty forest](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musty+room%2Cmusty+forest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @mplungjanI'm afraid this doesn't really answer my question.  I'm looking for a "specific" term that combines all the other smells as well (mustiness, moisture and the goods)a word that should apply only to confined spaces like cellars etc. (if that word exists obviously).

Comment: @mplungjanthe word you provided could be applied to forests too.

Comment: Hence you need to qualify it with "room"

Comment: @mplungjanThe smell of the musty pine forest for example is different from that coming from a cellar. That's what I mean by 'specific' term.

Comment: @user: You would very rarely hear the word "musty" applied to forests. Or indeed *any* context except an enclosed space/room, if you're describing "the atmosphere" as opposed to the smell of *one mouldy object*.

Comment: Indeed, _musty_ is an excellent choice, very apt for [cellars and basements](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=musty+room%2Cmusty+cellar%2Cmusty+car%2Cmusty+basement%2Cmusty+stable&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Chiming in here, but I would expect a *pine* forest to smell the opposite of musty. That's why they make those pine cleaners and dangly things to hang in cars, after all. Perhaps a fetid swamp or secluded cave could be described as musty, but it's most commonly applied to enclosed spaces and old books.

Comment: A dense forest with decaying grass and leaves would smell mustiness, wouldn't it?

Comment: Mustiness is the noun. So no. But all English speakers who ever smelled a cellar, will recognise musty

Comment: @user: I think your quibbling is counterproductive. Not every unique smell has its own name or word. There aren't different words for say, the aroma of homemade soup vs the aroma of baking bread; or, the smell of fresh-cut peonies vs the scent of a floral perfume. You asked about "a very characteristic kind of smell – a combination of the smell of moisture, mildew and the goods stored in the room." For six hours now, people have chimed in with _dank_ and _musty_; I don't think you're going to find more specific words than those.

Comment: @Tanninah no it wouldn't, a dense forest with decaying grass and leaves would smell _mouldy_ if anything. _Musty_ does imply closed spaces.

Comment: Interestingly, the next-best choice to _mustitiness_ may be _fustiness_. The _Oxford Universal Dictionary_ (1955) defines _fusty_ as "Stale-smelling, musty; smelling of mould or damp." Webster's says that _fusty_ probably derives from _foist_, meaning "wine cask." Still, I think that _mustiness_ is the best option.

Comment: wait...musty _flavor_?

Answer (score 4):

Before reading mplungjan's answer my immediate thought was **musty**. I am convinced that his answer fits perfectly Tanninah's need. Nevertheless, I provide alternative answers, which might agree with her more.

- [**Fetid**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fetid) adj; having a stale nauseating smell, as of decay
  [from Latin fētidus, from fētēre to stink; related to fūmus smoke]
- **Fetidness** n.

(I would not normally associate the smell of staleness and/or mouldy dampness with fetidness. Fetidness conjurs the idea of decay, rankness; an almost over powering smell which would cause the average person to hold back his/her breath. However in [**Moby thesaurus**](http://moby_thesaurus.enacademic.com/9587/fetid) it is said to be related to  musty and fusty.)

- [**Frowsty**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frowsty) adj; Chiefly British
  Having a stale smell; musty.

In [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frowsty) the example they give is: **a frowsty, mold-ridden flat in London's East End**

- **Frowstiness** n.

[image: D.H.lawrence: The Life of an Outsider]

- [**Frowzy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frowzy) adj; Having an unpleasant smell; musty: a frowzy pantry.
- **Frowziness** n.

[image: Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine]

- [**Stuffy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stuffy) adj; Lacking sufficient ventilation; close.
- **Stuffiness** n.

[image: Honore Balzac: Old Goriot]

I still prefer mustiness, though.

.

Answer (score 0):

Musty is one example but a word that I don't hear a lot in the U.S. However, Musky comes to mind when a smell is associated to the basement.

Definition - of or having a smell or taste of musk, or suggestive of musk.

(Musk-y)

Adjective

According to the source, "moisture" in the basement is often the cause of the smell.

Source: [CrawlSpace Repair](http://crawlspacerepair.com)

Comment: "Musty" is very commonly used in the US.  And "musky" refers to the smell of an animal, not a basement.

Answer (score -1):

Try the colloquial 'pong,' which the OED says means: 'An unpleasant smell; a stink.' 
[Etym. obscure.]

Comment: "pong" usually refers to a strong smell; is usually used only informally; and *does not relate specifically* to "a combination of the smell of moisture, mildew and the goods stored in the room", which is what the Q. asked for.

Answer (score -2):

How about Miasma? Although it may be a bit too strong a definition.

mi·as·ma
mīˈazmə,mēˈazmə/
nounliterary
a highly unpleasant or unhealthy smell or vapor

Comment: "Miasma" *does not relate specifically* to "a combination of the smell of moisture, mildew and the goods stored in the room", which is what the Q. asked for.